# Laravel Collection with Where(), Min() & pluck() Problem

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-7, collect

I'm struggling to grab specific date from an array of items. I want the 'id' of the minimum['lastUsed'] item.

Example

```
$getIdOfLastUsedItem = collect(//arrayOfItems)
            ->where('working', true) // works great & filters working items
            ->min('lastUsed') // returns 2
            ->pluck('id'); // Error


// arrayOfItems looks like this
array:11 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 6
    "working" => true
    "lastUsed" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 7
    "working" => false
    "lastUsed" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "id" => 8
    "working" => true
    "lastUsed" => 5
  ]...
```

My aim for $getIdOfLastUsedItem would return `'id' => 6` or just `6`

Comment: pluck('id') just change pluck to select('id') it will give you what you want

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan well that is a collection, not a query builder, and `min` is returning an integer so no methods can be called on it as its not an object

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan Does not work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with.

```
$getIdOfLastUsedItem = collect($array)
                ->where('working', true)
                ->sortBy('lastUsed')
                ->pluck('id')
                ->first()
        ;
```